# Why style.cursor method doesn't work on xPage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xpages, lotus-notes

It does work on Notes 8.5.x but does not on Notes 9.x.
Here is my simple xPage with just one button that sets cursor style to 'wait'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[document.body.style.cursor='wait';]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

When I click on this button and mouse is over it the cursor is still 'pointer' style. When I move mouse out a little bit it turns into 'wait' style. But if I move it a little bit more then it turns to 'default' style. Why it switches back from 'wait'? See picture above. jQuery works same way $("body").css("cursor", "progress");

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It happens when the individual `DOM` elements have their own style for `cursor` set. for example: your `a` elements and `button` elements may have style `cursor: pointer`. Which will take precedence over the cursor style set to the body.

Try setting this:

```
document.body.style.cssText =  "cursor:wait !important";
```

if that still doesn't solve the problem you might have to find the individual elemnts and set it like:

```
document.a.style.cssText =  "cursor:wait";
document.button.style.cssText =  "cursor:wait";
```

etc..

**TIP**: A better way would be add a class to the body on click and set this property to have your own style.

Answer (score 0):

solved with:

$('html,body').css('cursor', 'wait');
and
$('html,body').css('cursor', 'default');